# Make Django Admin Commands run automatically in deployment (apache2)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, apache2

I am creating an eCommerce site and want to delete rows of the `order` table after 20 days has passed. And I was successfully able to do that!
My code...

delete_old_orders.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from store.models import Order 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete objects older than 20 days'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Order.objects.filter(order_date__lte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=20)).delete()
        self.stdout.write('Deleted objects older than 10 days')
```

In which, just for your information my file location goes as...

```
store/
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            delete_old_orders.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Every time in order to run it, I need to run the code `python manage.py delete_old_orders` in the terminal.
However, this is in my local machine, when I want this to run **every day at 2am** in my server, which runs apache2 in Ubuntu. How should I deal with this?
Should I alter my config file in the server?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Simply, add this command to your server’s **crontab**.

Comment: Add celery to your project, and set a [periodic task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: yup just did a cron job, thanks a lot